# Stripe Checkout associate Checkout Session with existing Customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a Stripe Checkout page which allows customers to start a subscription. I then have a webhook which will start the account registration process to the site after a successful Checkout session. The Checkout page is public, i.e., at the time the Checkout session is active, I don't have a customer id.

The flow works well, for brand-new users or existing users. I have it set so that existing customers may only have 1 active subscription, so if you are an existing customer/user with an active subscription, and you hit that Stripe Checkout page, and enter in your email address, it will push you to a self-service portal.

However, where this breaks down is when the subscription terminates, either if it was cancelled by the customer or was just allowed to lapse. In this case, if the customer wants to renew, they can get back to that public Sign Up page, get into a Stripe Checkout session, and subscribe anew. This creates another Customer object, in Stripe. I can handle this gracefully on the app-side, so that we don't re-register the same user by their email address. But in Stripe, now there are two customer objects with the same email address. If this user then enters the self-service portal, now it will only shows transactions/invoices for the most current customer object; not the one that had a previous subscription.

I started going down this path, where in my code, after receiving a checkout.session.completed event, I check for the existence of another customer with the same email address, attempt to move the subscription and payment details to that customer, and delete the newly created customer from the checkout. However, this just seemed so messy and prone to errors.

Is there any way to check during a Stripe Checkout session, without knowing the user beforehand, if a user with the same email address as one that is already in Stripe - whether or not that have an active subscription - is trying to complete a session? If so, I do not want a new Customer object, but I want a new subscription on the existing Customer by that email. Is my only recourse to alter my flow, to have a form to ask for the email address to lookup the Stripe customer, *before* pushing the user to the Checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

There's a "Limit customers to 1 subscription" option in your Stripe Dashboard, you can enable it to limit your customer to have only 1 subscription. See this [page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/limit-subscriptions#direct-your-customers-to-the-customer-portal-or-your-website) for details.

Comment: Yes, I have that option enabled. From the page you sent:

You can redirect customers that already have an **active** subscription to the customer portal or your website to manage their subscription.

My problem is when the customer exists, but doesn't have an active subscription anymore. I don't want to create a new customer, but use the existing one, if they re-subscribe.

Comment: In that case you need to collect the email address in your own UI first, and pass it to the List all customers API (https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list#list_customers-email). If there's a match, use the matched customer to create a checkout session.